# Manage static link in js libraries within django

Tags: javascript, python, django

So I was trying to add an audio recording function to my website developed with *django*.

I wanted to do something similar as https://github.com/addpipe/simple-web-audio-recorder-demo so I started by trying to run it without modification.

I took the same html as in the git linked above, put the `js/` folder in my `static/` folder, and simply changed the following lines *(index.html, line 32-33)*

```
<script src="js/WebAudioRecorder.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

for

```
{% load static %}
<script src={% static "js/WebAudioRecorder.min.js" %}></script>
<script src={% static "js/app.js" %}></script>
```

These js files load correctly, but the problem is that when I click record on my website, I get a `"GET /myapp/record/js/WebAudioRecorderWav.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404` error in my django server.

`WebAudioRecorderWav.min.js` is called within `WebAudioRecorder.min.js`. I tried to use the `{% load static %}` trick in the js file, but it doesn’t work.

What would be the correct way to work around this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Isn't that what the `.workerDir` config setting is for? Try setting it to `{% static 'js' %}` when initialising your `WebAudioRecorder` (which means you cannot do that in `app.js` but have to do that in the HTML template itself.) Alternatively create a a `var` in your template setting `var jsFilesPath = "{% static 'js' %}"` and use that inside `app.js`

Comment: @dirkgroten thanks, I did as you said and it worked !

That is setting a var in my template and using it in `app.js`. The only thing I had to change was adding a `/` after `js`, i.e. `var jsFilesPath = "{% static 'js/' %}"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `workerDir` setting to set the correct path to the other imported js files. Probably your recorder is initialised in *app.js*, where you cannot use template tags like `{% static %}`. The best way is to create a global variable in your template before loading *app.js*:

In your HTML template:

```
<script>var jsFilesPath = "{% static 'js/' %}"</script>
<script src="{% static 'js/app.js' %}"></script>
```

In your app.js:

```
if (typeof jsFilesPath !== "undefined") {
    audioRecorder = new WebAudioRecorder(sourceNode, {
      workerDir: jsFilesPath     // must end with slash
    });
}
```

Comment: It helped me to find my way to the solution. Nice explanation!